# illegal expression

Tags: java

Os paso todo mi Main. el error dice expresion ilegal pero esta copiado y pegado de un codigo del profesor de un archivo suyo.el error es en el metodo serializable

```
package tarea7;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author ck
 */
public class GestionDelMazo {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File miFichero = new File("Coleccion.dat");
        Mazo m = null;
        if (!miFichero.exists()) {
            m = new Mazo();
            System.out.println(m.toString());
        } else {
           m = deserializa();
        }

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean salir = false;
        int opcion; // Guardaremos la opcion del usuario

        while (!salir) {
            System.out.println("*********************************************");
            System.out.println("1. Añadir una nueva carta");
            System.out.println("2. Buscar carta por su nombre");
            System.out.println("3. Eliminar una carta");
            System.out.println("4. Listar  todas las cartas");
            System.out.println("4. Listar  todas las cartas nuevas");
            System.out.println("5. Listar  todas las cartas segunda mano");
            System.out.println("6. Buscar la carta mas cara");
            System.out.println("7. Buscar la carta mas barata");
            System.out.println("8. Buscar la carta mas antigua");
            System.out.println("9. Salir");
            System.out.println("*********************************************");

            System.out.println("Elija una de las opciones");

            opcion = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());

            switch (opcion) {
                case 1:
                    CartaDeRol[] mazo1 = new CartaDeRol[10];
                    String aux = "",
                     aux1 = "",
                     aux2 = "";
                    int aux3 = 0,
                     aux4 = 0;
                    double aux5 = 0;
                    CartaDeRol carta1 = new CartaDeRol();
                    System.out.println("nombre de la carta: " + aux);
                    aux = entrada.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("tipo de carta: " + aux1);
                    aux1 = entrada.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Descripcion: " + aux2);
                    aux2 = entrada.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Cuantos dueños a tenido antes? " + aux3);
                    aux3 = entrada.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Año de creacion: " + aux4);
                    aux4 = entrada.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Precio: " + aux5);
                    aux5 = entrada.nextDouble();
                    carta1.setNombre(aux);
                    carta1.setTipo(aux1);
                    carta1.setDescripcion(aux2);
                    carta1.setNumDueniosAnt(aux3);
                    carta1.setAnioCreacion(aux4);
                    carta1.setPrecio(aux5);
                    m.addCarta(carta1);
                    System.out.println(m.addCarta(carta1));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    String nombreCarta = "";
                    System.out.println("nombre de la carta a buscar: " + nombreCarta);
                    nombreCarta = entrada.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(m.buscarCartaXNombre(nombreCarta));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    String nombreCartaB = "";
                    System.out.println("nombre de la carta a borrar: " + nombreCartaB);
                    nombreCartaB = entrada.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(m.buscarCartaXNombre(nombreCartaB));

                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println(m.listaCartaN());

                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println(m.listarCartasV());

                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.println(m.buscarCartaCara());

                    break;
                case 7:
                    m.BuscarCartaBarata();

                    break;
                case 8:
                    m.devCartaAntigua();

                    break;
                case 9:
                    salir = true;
                    entrada.close();
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Solo numeros entre 1 y 9");
            }

        }


    public static void serializa(Mazo m) {
        FileOutputStream f;
        try {
            f = new FileOutputStream("Coleccion.dat");
            ObjectOutputStream fis;
            fis = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
            fis.writeObject(m);
            fis.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GestionDelMazo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GestionDelMazo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static Mazo deserializa() {
        Mazo m = null;

        FileInputStream fe;
        try {
            fe = new FileInputStream("Coleccion.dat");
            ObjectInputStream fie = new ObjectInputStream(fe);
            m = (Mazo) fie.readObject();
            fie.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            m.setNumelementos(0);
            Logger.getLogger(GestionDelMazo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            m.setNumelementos(0);
            Logger.getLogger(GestionDelMazo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            m.setNumelementos(0);
            Logger.getLogger(GestionDelMazo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return m;
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda he de entregar el trabajo esta noche y aun me queda esto y un par de cosas mas

Comment: Te falta cerrar un corchete compañero, cuidado con esos copy/plastes que son traicioneros!

Answer (score 1):

Estas seguro de que esta bien el codigo? Revisandolo he visto que hacia falta cerrar el metodo `Main`.
Aqui te dejo el codigo.

```js
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author ck
 */
public class GestionDelMazo {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File miFichero = new File("Coleccion.dat");
        Mazo m = null;
        if (!miFichero.exists()) {
            m = new Mazo();
            System.out.println(m.toString());
        } else {
           m = deserializa();
        }

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean salir = false;
        int opcion; // Guardaremos la opcion del usuario

        while (!salir) {
            System.out.println("*********************************************");
            System.out.println("1. Añadir una nueva carta");
            System.out.println("2. Buscar carta por su nombre");
            System.out.println("3. Eliminar una carta");
            System.out.println("4. Listar  todas las cartas");
            System.out.println("4. Listar  todas las cartas nuevas");
            System.out.println("5. Listar  todas las cartas segunda mano");
            System.out.println("6. Buscar la carta mas cara");
            System.out.println("7. Buscar la carta mas barata");
            System.out.println("8. Buscar la carta mas antigua");
            System.out.println("9. Salir");
            System.out.println("*********************************************");

            System.out.println("Elija una de las opciones");

            opcion = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());

            switch (opcion) {
                case 1:
                    CartaDeRol[] mazo1 = new CartaDeRol[10];
                    String aux = "",
                     aux1 = "",
                     aux2 = "";
                    int aux3 = 0,
                     aux4 = 0;
                    double aux5 = 0;
                    CartaDeRol carta1 = new CartaDeRol();
                    System.out.println("nombre de la carta: " + aux);
                    aux = entrada.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("tipo de carta: " + aux1);
                    aux1 = entrada.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Descripcion: " + aux2);
                    aux2 = entrada.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Cuantos dueños a tenido antes? " + aux3);
                    aux3 = entrada.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Año de creacion: " + aux4);
                    aux4 = entrada.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Precio: " + aux5);
                    aux5 = entrada.nextDouble();
                    carta1.setNombre(aux);
                    carta1.setTipo(aux1);
                    carta1.setDescripcion(aux2);
                    carta1.setNumDueniosAnt(aux3);
                    carta1.setAnioCreacion(aux4);
                    carta1.setPrecio(aux5);
                    m.addCarta(carta1);
                    System.out.println(m.addCarta(carta1));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    String nombreCarta = "";
                    System.out.println("nombre de la carta a buscar: " + nombreCarta);
                    nombreCarta = entrada.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(m.buscarCartaXNombre(nombreCarta));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    String nombreCartaB = "";
                    System.out.println("nombre de la carta a borrar: " + nombreCartaB);
                    nombreCartaB = entrada.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(m.buscarCartaXNombre(nombreCartaB));

                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println(m.listaCartaN());

                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println(m.listarCartasV());

                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.println(m.buscarCartaCara());

                    break;
                case 7:
                    m.BuscarCartaBarata();

                    break;
                case 8:
                    m.devCartaAntigua();

                    break;
                case 9:
                    salir = true;
                    entrada.close();
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Solo numeros entre 1 y 9");
            }

        }
    }


    public static void serializa(Mazo m) {
        FileOutputStream f;
        try {
            f = new FileOutputStream("Coleccion.dat");
            ObjectOutputStream fis;
            fis = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
            fis.writeObject(m);
            fis.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GestionDelMazo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GestionDelMazo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static Mazo deserializa() {
        Mazo m = null;

        FileInputStream fe;
        try {
            fe = new FileInputStream("Coleccion.dat");
            ObjectInputStream fie = new ObjectInputStream(fe);
            m = (Mazo) fie.readObject();
            fie.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            m.setNumelementos(0);
            Logger.getLogger(GestionDelMazo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            m.setNumelementos(0);
            Logger.getLogger(GestionDelMazo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            m.setNumelementos(0);
            Logger.getLogger(GestionDelMazo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return m;
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias me di cuenta al final